# Random 5 different numbers

Tags: java

I have this class and it is working fine for me. It give 5 digit random number. What 
I can´t achieve is that the 5 numbers be different from each other, I mean no repeat it number in the 5 digit.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Test
{

    public int[] dedo()
    {
        Random diceRoller = new Random();
        int[] cifra = new int[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < cifra.length; i++)
        {
            int roll = diceRoller.nextInt(9);
            cifra[i] = roll;
            System.out.print(roll);
        }
        return cifra;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not really random if you constrain the result like this, but a quick nasty way to do this would be with `Collections.shuffle()`

```
List<Integer> digits = Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
Collections.shuffle(digits);
return digits.subList(0, 4).toArray();
```

Comment: Thank you man. But like you said it is no random.